# Wix - Detect whether Excel is 32bit or 64bit

Tags: excel, installation, wix, windows-installer

I've seen couple of similar questions but nothing adress to doing this from wix file. I am using the following snippet to detect whether Excel is installed.

```
<!-- Check if Excel is installed -->
    <Property Id="EXCEL2010">
      <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2010" Guid="{8B1BF0B4-A1CA-4656-AA46-D11C50BC55A4}" Type="file"/>
    </Property>        
    <Condition Message="Microsoft Excel 2010 required.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR EXCEL2010]]>
    </Condition>
```

But i would like to do additional check whether Excel 2010 is x86 or x64 and to display some message if possible. Is there some similar way to do this from the same file?

Comment: I've seen that. But I don't know how to do it from wix file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the Office 2010 ProPlus media and I see the following differences:

Component Guids:

Global_Excel_Core {8B1BF0B4-A1CA-4656-AA46-D11C50BC55A4}  64bit

Global_Excel_Core {538F6C89-2AD5-4006-8154-C6670774E980}  32bit

That might be better for you.

```
<Property Id="EXCEL2010X86">
  <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2010x86" Guid="{538F6C89-2AD5-4006-8154-C6670774E980}" Type="file"/>
</Property>        
<Property Id="EXCEL2010X64">
  <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2010x64" Guid="{8B1BF0B4-A1CA-4656-AA46-D11C50BC55A4}" Type="file"/>
</Property>        
<Condition Message="Microsoft Excel 2010 (32bit or 64bit) is required.">Installed OR EXCEL2010X86 OR EXCEL2010X64</Condition>
```

Comment: Yes, I'am working on that post right now and trying to create RegisterSearch element since I am not familiar with wix...

Comment: I'm going to download and install to see what gets laid down when only Excel is installed

Comment: Thanks, but can you please clarify a bit? I am not sure how to use this in order to check for x86 or x64?

Comment: I've updated the answer again. It seemed to me that your question already showed an example of a search and a condition with a Boolean statement so I assumed you'd be able to scale it to the next level.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic now. I upvoted and will give it a try to accept it afterwards. Can you please share a link for this GUIDs? I will also need x64 and x32 Guids for 2013... Thanks.